# Automounted drive can only be accessed by root

Tags: mount, fstab, user, git

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi as a git server using the instructions I found at [www.sitepoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-git-server/). Rather then have the files stored on the SD card I've mounted an external USB drive instead as it will give me more space for the files. This is formatted as FAT

It's *almost* working the way I want it, but when I clone my repo I get the following error:

```
$ git clone git-user@myPi:/path/to/my/repo
Cloning into 'repo'...
git-user@myPi's password:
fatal: '/path/to/my/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

If I change 'git-user' to the root user name and try again git works as expected, so I think there is something wrong with the 'git-user'.

Digging a bit further, if I ssh onto the pi as git-user and try to *cd* into /path/to/my/repo I get a "No such file or directory", but if I *su* to the root user and try again then it works. From what I can tell the external drive can only be accessed by root, and this is where I get stuck.

I've run ls -l and can see that all users have permissions to read and write all the directories in the path that 'git-user' can't *cd* into

I've also checked the '/etc/fstab' file - my drive is mounted as:

```
UUID=A89B-BA8D /path/to/my vfat defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail,umask=000 0 0
```

My understanding was that the **users** setting was there to allow all users to read the drive.

Obviously I've missed something, but I'm not sure were to go next

Comment: I do not know if this will help, but to last number on the mount is the sequence of mount, 0 is for /proc, 1 is for root and everything else should be greater than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question so that if anybody has the same problem they might find the help they need. However, for full disclosure, I've got to say that I wouldn't have been able to solve it without the comments provided by @moo in the previous answer....

My problem was that the mount point for the drive was in the form `/path/to/my`, the important bit being that there are three levels of directories, not the usual two. It turns out that I need to grant read-write permissions to `/path/to` as well as `/path/to/my` for a non-root user to be able to access the drive.

In my case that non-root user is the git client.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was in the choice you made for using the `FAT` filesystem.

***Why?*** `FAT` has no concept of (does not have the meta-data built into the filesystem) to recognize users and 'modes' (think `chmod`). I'm not sure that `git` will actually "work" (in the fullest sense of the word) with a `FAT` filesystem.

You should use a USB drive that is formatted as `ext4`.

You might want to look around for a different tutorial - the one you're following is 2016 vintage - nearly 8 years old now.  I have nothing against the tutorial - I didn't even read it - but I noticed the date stamp.

Comment: Hi @Seamus, thanks for the reply. I was hoping to use FAT because this Raspberry Pi is more that just a git server; the other thing I've installed is Samba so I can use it as a file server as well. The idea being that I can unmount the drive and then connect it to a Windows machine (OK, so it won't be a good ideas to play with the git database but I can get my music and photos). I don't think I can do that with a *nix file system like ext4 (can I?)

Comment: You are right about the tutorial being a bit old, I was originally working of another one on a pi forum that was 'only' 5 years old. The basic instructions were more or less the same but it didn't talk about setting up another user which has to be a good thing. If you know of a good alternative that I'd be interested in knowing about it.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use ex/vFAT if you want Unix permissions support. Perhaps create separate partitions for different purposes? Or abandon the idea of being able to mount the USB drive natively in Windows and stick to Samba over the network for this disk (not a problem with ext3/4)

Comment: @moo, is it possible to set up the drive so all users have access to all files on it?

Comment: Yes: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions

Comment: You can (I'm _told_ this) mount,read&write an `ext4` partition in Windows **only** with 3rd party software; [for example](https://superuser.com/questions/1748363/how-do-i-write-to-a-usb-drive-formatted-as-ext4-in-windows-11). **But** I hope you've not forgotten that once you've set up your Samba server, **you can access that share from your Windows machine**; i.e. while it is plugged into your RPi. This is the _magic_ of a network file system like Samba; it can be `ext4` on the server-side, but FAT on the client-side.

Comment: @moo, can I just check you sent me the correct link - it appears to be a tutorial on `chmod`. The problem I've got it that a FAT disc can only be read by root. Because it's FAT the disc doesn't have all the permission bits and groups that the tutorial describes. From what I can see it appears that the disc has been mounted so that only root can read it. I had expected that the entry in /etc/fstab would allow anybody to read it, but I'm now thinking that this isn't correct

Comment: @seamus, thanks for the advice, but in my case I occasionally want to be able to take the disc outside of my network and use it on other people's machines. I think FAT, or at least something Windows can read natively, is what I need

Comment: In that case, it might help to change the permissions at the point of mounting the FAT partition. Is this any use? https://askubuntu.com/questions/251206/mount-usb-drive-with-write-permissions-for-everyone-or-specific-user

Comment: @moo, Thanks for the post link - I've got it working now  :-)  I think the problem was the mount point was in the format  `/media/<app>/<drive>`, but not all of the directories had the right permissions.  If you would like to turn your comments into an answer I will accept it.   @Seamus, thank you for your advice. It was also appreciated.

Comment: Great to hear you got it working. So was this a Unix-permissions compatible partition with the incorrect file permissions or restrictively mounted FAT partition?

Comment: I think it was the file permissions that were wrong because that's all I had to change. The trick was to grant permissions to all directories in the mount path. I had only granted permissions in the final directory. I didn't have to change the fstab mount permissions, but for reference they are documented in the question